# find the complex Fourier series of the given periodic function $f(t) = e^{-t}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

I am trying to find the complex Fourier series of the given periodic function $$f(t) = e^{-t}$$
over the interval $(-3,3)$ and $f(t+6) = f(t)$

**My attempt:**

The half period of the function is $3$, therefore the coefficient $c_0$ is

$$c_0 = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{6} \int_{-3}^{3}e^{-t} dt = \frac{1}{6}\left[ -e^{-t}\big|_{-3}^{3}\right] = -\frac{e^{-3}}{6} + \frac{e^3}{6 } = \frac{e^3-e^{-3}}{6}$$

Then for $n \ne 0 $

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(t)e^{-int}dt = \frac{1}{6}\int_{-3}^{3} e^{-t}e^{-int} dt = \frac{1}{6} \int_{-3}^{3} e^{(-1-in)t} = \frac{1}{6} \left[ \frac{1}{(-1-in)} e^{(-1-in)t} \bigg|^3_{-3} \right] \\ = \frac{1}{6} \left[ \frac{e^{-t} e^{-int}}{-1-in}\bigg| ^3_{-3} \right] = \frac{1}{6(-1-in)} (e^{-3}e^{-3int}-e^3e^{3int}) $$

So my question is how do I use $f(t+6) = f(t)$ and then put all these things together to find the complex Fourier series of the given function?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $\pi$ or 2 here and there?

Comment: So instead of 2L which I said was 6 it should be $2\pi $?

Comment: No you wrote right, you have done it, that's the series. The fact that $f(t)=f(t+6)$ is needed because $f$ has to be periodic of some period in order to take it's fourier series.

Comment: So I am correct in finding $c_0$ and $c_n $? Then how do I put them together to find the solution

Comment: Well just use the definition of the fourier series, $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{int}, \forall t \in [-3,3)$ and then you have it for all t since $f(t)=f(t+6)$.

Comment: there is something fishy here. $f(t) = e^{-t}$ is not periodic for real $t$ (but you take $t$ from a real interval). (note that $e^{-it}$ is periodic, but that's not what you are looking at).

Comment: @Thomas so what have I done wrong?

Comment: I did not read your calculations. I just noted that the function you are looking at is not periodic. Or do you intend to work with a periodic (and discontinuous) extension -- i.e. define $f$ outside of $(-3, 3) $ by periodicity?

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure, I thought this was how the question was done

Comment: @chak so then the complex fourier series would be $f(x) = \frac{e^3-e^{-3}}{6} + \sum_{n= -\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{6(-1-in)} (e^{-3}e^{-3int}-e^3e^{3int}) e^{int}$?

Comment: @Thomas it says in the question it is a periodic function?

Comment: Look at formulas (30) and (31) on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html which (to be frank) is more trustworthy than many of the comments here.

Comment: @kimchilover so then should I use $$c_n = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(t) e^{-\frac{in\pi t}{L}}dt$$ instead of $$c_n = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(t) e^{-int}dt$$

Comment: yes sorry i made confusion with the notation that was for $(0,2\pi)$ . $e^{2\pi int}$ is the o.n. basis for $(0,1)$, so for $(−3,3)$ you have $e^{\pi int/3}$ . Sorry again @jh123.

Comment: Also @kimchilover thanks for pointing that out. I will pay more attention next time!

Comment: [Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2529078/418542) related to the same Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

The complex Fourier expansion of a $T$-periodic function $t\mapsto ft)$ has the form
$$f(t)\rightsquigarrow \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_ke^{2k\pi i t/T}\ ,$$whereby the coefficients $c_k$ are given by the formula
$$c_k={1\over T}\int_{\rm 1\ full\ period}f(t)e^{-2k\pi i t/T}\>dt\qquad(k\in{\mathbb Z}) .\tag{1}$$
In the case at hand the period length is $6$, and we use as "$1$ full period" the interval $[{-3},3]$, in which $f(t)$ is given by the simple expression $e^{-t}$. The formula $(1)$ then gives
$$c_k={1\over 6}\int_{-3}^3\exp\left(-\left(1+{k\pi i \over 3}\right)t\right)\>dt\qquad(k\in{\mathbb Z})\ .\tag{2}$$
Since $1+{k\pi i\over3}\ne0$ for all $k\in{\mathbb Z}$ we can compute the integrals $(2)$ without any exception handling. The result is
$$c_k={\sinh(3+ik\pi)\over 3+ik\pi}={(-1)^k\over 3+ik\pi}\sinh 3\qquad(k\in{\mathbb Z})\ .\tag{3}$$

Comment: thanks for your submission! do I not need to calculate $c_0?$

Comment: Formula $(3)$ is valid for all $k\in{\mathbb Z}$. When $k=0$ you obtain $c_0={1\over3}\sinh 3$.

Comment: I have submitted a answer to this solution that is different than yours, have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$$A(n) = \frac{1}{6}\int_{-3}^3 e^{-t}e^{\frac{-2\pi int}{6}} dt = \frac{1}{6} \int_{-3}^3 e^{(-(\frac{3+n\pi i }{3}t)}dt = \frac{1}{6} \frac{-3}{3+n\pi i} e^{(-(\frac{3+n\pi i }{3 }t)} \bigg| _{-3}^3 \\ = \frac{-1}{2(3+n\pi i )} [e^{-(3+n\pi i ))} - e^{3+n\pi i }] = (\frac{1}{3+n\pi i })e^{n\pi i }\frac{(e^3-e^{-3})}{2} = (\frac{1}{3+n\pi i})(cos(n\pi)+isin(n\pi))*\frac{(e^3-e^{-3})}{2} = \frac{1}{3+n\pi i } ((-1)^n+0i)cosh3 = \frac{(-1)^ncosh3}{3+n\pi i }$$

Therefore,

$$f(t) \approx \sum_\infty^{-\infty} A(n) e^{\frac{2\pi int}{6}} = \sum_\infty^{-\infty} \left[ \frac{(-1)^ncosh(3)}{3+n\pi i }\right]e^{\frac{\pi i nt}{3}}$$

Comment: One has $(e^3-e^{-3})/2=\sinh 3$.

Comment: Okay so this answer is correct when I fix the mistake and say sinh3 instead of cosh?